# WPF Textbox selection lost when try to set cursor at end after selection

Tags: wpf

I want to set cursor at end in wpf textbox after selecting all of its text.

I am able to select the text using

```
textBox.SelectAll();
```

or

```
textBox.Select(int start, int lenght);
```

But after that when I try to set caret at end using `textBox.CaretIndex`, selection gets cleared.

I want selection to stay in place and cursor blinking at end.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken I've never seen a selection and a blinking cursor at same time. In the context of input selection shows what to replace, caret is the indicator for no selection. Is it highlighting what you want?

Answer (score 0):

To position the cursor at the end of the contents of a TextBox control, call the Select method and specify the selection start position equal to the length of the text content, and a selection length of 0. [Source.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752349.aspx)

`textBox.Select(textBox.Text.Length, 0);`